# javascript bind an event handler to horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

Is there a way in javascript to bind an event handler to a horizontal scroll as opposed to the generic scroll event which is fired when the user scrolls horizontally and vertically? I want to trigger an event only when the user scrolls horizontally.

I searched around for an answer to this question, but couldn't seem to find anything.

Thanks!

P.S. My apologies if I'm using some terminology incorrectly. I'm fairly new to javascript.

**UPDATE**

Thanks so much for all your answers! In summary, it looks like you are all saying that this isn't supported in javascript, but I that I can accomplish the functionality with something like this (using jQuery) [(jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/EsPk7/7/):

```
var oldScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

$(window).bind('scroll', function () {
    if (oldScrollTop == $(window).scrollTop())
        //scrolled horizontally
    else {
        //scrolled vertically
        oldScrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    }
});​
```

That's all I needed to know. Thanks again!

Comment: Please see my new answer that may be of use to you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering from my phone, so unable to provide code at the moment.

What you'll need to do is subscribe to the scroll event. There isn't a specific one for vertical/horizontal.

Next, you'll need to get some measurements about the current display area. You'll need to measure the window.clientHeight and window.clientWidth.

Next, get window.top and window.left. This will tell you where position of the viewport is, ie if it's greater than 0 then scroll bars have been used.

It's pretty simple math from here to get what you need. If no one else has provided a code example in the next few hours I'll try to do so.

Edit: 
A bit further information.

You must capture the scroll event. You also need to store the initial window.top and window.left properties somewhere. Whenever the scroll event happens, do a simple check to see if the current top/left values differ from the stores value.

At this point, if either are different you can trigger your own custom events to indicate vertical or horizontal scrolling. If you are using jQuery, this is very easy. If you are writing js without library assistance, it's easy too but a little more involved.

Do some searches for event dispatching in js.

You can then write any other code you want to subscribe to your custom events without needing to tie them together with method calls.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a jQuery plugin for you that lets you attach functions to the `scrollh` event.

[See it in action at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/XgYpP/).

```
/* Enable "scrollh" event jQuery plugin */
(function ($) {
    $.fn.enableHScroll = function() {
        function handler(el) {
           var lastPos = el
              .on('scroll', function() {
                 var newPos = $(this).scrollLeft();
                 if (newPos !== lastPos) {
                     $(this).trigger('scrollh', newPos - lastPos);
                     lastPos = newPos;
                 }
              })
              .scrollLeft();
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            var el = $(this);
            if (!el.data('hScrollEnabled')) {
                el.data('hScrollEnabled', true);                 
                handler(el);
            }
        });
    }
}(jQuery));
```

It's this easy to use:

```
$('#container')
    .enableHScroll()
    .on('scrollh', function(obj, offset) {
        $('#info').val(offset);
    });
```

Please note that scroll events come very fast. Even if you click in the scrollbar to jump to a new position, many scroll events are generated. You may want to adjust this code to wait a short time and accumulate all the changes in position during that time before firing the hscroll event.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, ErikE.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the same [`scroll`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event, but within your handler use the [`scrollLeft`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) function to see if the scrollbar moved horizontally from the last time the event was fired. If the scrollbar did not move then just return from your handler. Otherwise update your variable to the new position and take action.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the the `x` value of the page changes and ignore your `y` value.

If the `x` value changes: There is your horizontal scroll.

Answer (score 1):

With page-load, store the initial scrollbar positions for both in two variables (presumably both will be 0). Next, whenever a scroll event occurs, find the `scrollleft` and `scrolltop` properties. If the `scrollleft` property's value is different and `scrolltop`'s value is same as compared to their earlier values, that's a horizontal scroll. Then set the values of the variables to the new scroll values.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no special event for scroll horizontal (it is for global scroll), but you can try to check the position of content by property `.scrollLeft` and if it's different from the previous value it means that the user scrolled content horizontally.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. It will detect a horizontal scroll when the user scrolls right the first time. After that, even if he scrolls up or down, `scrollleft` will still show to be more than 0, as he hasn't scrolled back left, and thus it will falsely register as horizontal scroll.

Comment: Now I reading it, you right. Maybe my answer was a little bit messy... he should remember last value of `scrollLeft` property and compare new and old one.

Comment: `scrollLeft()` isn't a property, it's a function. Trivial, I know, but let's not mislead beginners by having them try to use it without the parentheses. :)

Comment: scrollLeft is function in jQuery :) In vanilla js is a property: https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/DOM/element.scrollLeft