# Div fixed position horizontally with vertical movement upon horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website which scrolls horizontally. It is to depict travelling across a scene. What I want to do is have a div containing an image of the sun to stay in the same position horizontally but move down vertically as the website is scrolled, so that at the start of the 'journey' the sun div is high in the sky and as you progress through the site the sun div 'sets'

I can't think of a way to do this and was hoping someone might be able to help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like .scroll() if you'r using JQuery.

[.scroll API](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/)
If you look at the comments and adapt that to horizontal scrolling i think it might work.

Did another search and found this as well: [javascript-bind-an-event-handler-to-horizontal-scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729859/javascript-bind-an-event-handler-to-horizontal-scroll)

Comment: thanks for replying. I am new to JQuery so couldnt figure out how to adapt that for what I need. I know that I want the vertical position of the div to be relative to the scroll position so if the site is scrolled so many pixels to the right the div will respond by moving position down vertically. What I really need is example code I know its a lot to ask for people to figure this out for me but I am so dumb when it comes to JQuery! Thanks again for trying to help me!

Comment: modified the fiddle from the last example, its not pretty and im sure someone can make it better, but it works: http://jsfiddle.net/cuGMd/

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I need it to do! As I said before I am dumb with certain web things. What javascript libraries or other scripts do I need to download to make this work in a site? I tried to implement and the div did not move upon scrolling it just stayed fixed in position. Thanks for your patience with an obvious idiot :)

Comment: You need to add JQuery as I mentioned, it can be downloaded her: http://jquery.com/download/

And here's a beginners guide: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=231

Comment: Hi, sorry work got crazy didnt get a chance to get back to you. I couldn't get it to work. I think its because I'm not familiar with jsfiddle. I think if I could see the code of a working example without all the other code from the jsfiddle site I could figure it out. As it stands I am left feeling stupid lol

Comment: Post the code you got: need to see the HTML and CSS for the div as well as you the js for moving the div. Then we can help you point out whats wrong.