# onscroll event not firing upon horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The following code is never executed when I scroll the browser horizontally:

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    alert("onscroll working");
};
```

However, the function is executed when I scroll vertically. I've tried it in Google Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, so the browser is likely not the issue. Anyone have any ideas as to why the method isn't executed when I scroll horizontally?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729859/javascript-bind-an-event-handler-to-horizontal-scroll

Comment: Thanks, maybe I'll just try this and explicitly code in the horizontal scrolling functionality, although I'm still confused as to why it doesn't work by default.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  alert('Scroll activated.')
});
```

Hope this works for you!

http://codepen.io/jiemushi/pen/LkjJzp

Comment: This doesn't work either for some reason, I'm not sure why. Thank you though!!